# Lossless Image Optimization for JPG, GIF and PNG in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, optimization

Within my site I have images only which takes a lot of time for page load. I've developed site using WordPress. I've used WP.Smush It plugin for optimization but still not getting proper output. Is there any free tool or script to do such task?

I don't want to lose quality of images. I've .jpg, .png and .gif images format.

Comment: ,I have posted answer of your question,Please check it !

Answer (score 0):

@Ashish, Check below **wp-plugin CW Image Optimizer** for automatically and losslessly optimize your images as you upload them to your blog.

It can also optimize the images that you have already uploaded in the past.

**CW Image Optimizer** uses lossless optimization techniques, **your image quality will be exactly the same before and after the optimization.**

The only thing that will change is your file size.

Please check [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cw-image-optimizer/) link.

Comment: I am using WP on shared hosting. I've installed this plugin and it says.....CW Image Optimizer requires littleutils. You are missing: opt-png, opt-jpg, opt-gif...... What to do?

Comment: I think you need to install littleutils on your server.